# Xfce Cannot open Window manager and window manager tweaks

Tags: xfce, xubuntu

I installed today a new linux distro ENSO OS based on Xubuntu and is really good, its mac like in appereance. But I have a problem, I wanted to change my theme using window manager but refuses to open. I also tried to open through terminal but no luck and I'm facing an error:

```
xfwm4-Message: 22:00:28.663: Another Window Manager (Mutter(Gala)) is already running on screen :0.0
xfwm4-Message: 22:00:28.663: To replace the current window manager, try "--replace"

(xfwm4:1979): xfwm4-WARNING **: 22:00:28.663: Could not find a screen to manage, exiting
```

I tried to contact the support but I'm not getting a response until now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error message, your distribution is not running xfwm4 by default. Rather it is running Mutter which is the Gnome window manager. So, not being able to open Window Manager and Window Manager Tweaks is likely that way by design. In order to open these, you would need to change your window manager to xfwm4. However, I would proceed with caution because this could break some functionality intended by the distribution developers.
If you decide to switch to xfwm4, make sure it is installed first. I cannot imagine it not being installed, but you can check with the command `which xfwm4`. If installed, it'll return the path `/usr/bin/xfwm4`.
If changing your window manager for some reason does not work and you do not have a window manager functioning after attempting to switch, open a terminal and run the command `xfwm4 --replace`. (However, beforehand, make sure you have a keyboard shortcut set to open a terminal in Keyboard > Application Shortcuts.) Then open Settings Editor > xfce4-session > /sessions/Failsafe/Client0_Command. Click on the setting there and click the Reset button at the bottom. 
[Here is a post on changing the window manager in Xfce.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143376/how-to-change-xfce4-default-window-manager)

This command worked on my system for changing the window manager to xfwm4:
`xfconf-query --channel xfce4-session --property /sessions/Failsafe/Client0_Command --type string --set 'xfwm4' --type string --set '--replace'`

Comment: Was a new distro and also other users faced this problem, and the team is fixing this. Anyway I tested some days Enso and was just a xubuntu with a lot customization,so I switched to Mx Linux and I'm fine. Enso was really cool and I will install again after the team fix the bugs. So thank you for answer. Yea its right the xfwm4 is not running by default as you said.